# Angular + CoffeeScript JS fiddle errors

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, jsfiddle

This JavaScript JSFiddle works -> http://jsfiddle.net/franklovecchio/E3YEt/

This CoffeeScript JSFiddle does not work -> http://jsfiddle.net/franklovecchio/E3YEt/230/

Appending `angular.bootstrap(document, [])` was supposed to make it work, but it does not.  What is wrong?

The error I see in the console is "Uncaught Error: No module: Test"

Comment: Why are there `<script>` tags in the CSS pane?

Comment: The JSFiddle I forked this from had them in there. It doesn't work even if you select the Angular option from the left-panel. http://jsfiddle.net/franklovecchio/E3YEt/230/. (updated question)

Comment: They both work for me.

Comment: See updated question. "Uncaught Error: No module: Test"

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are trying to initiate the `bootstrap` process with the whole document - which is not an HTML Element.

I updated you fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/a8upx/). I changed it, so that the app gets bootstrapped over the div, not the document itself.